# Client side less compilation not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am facing a problem when I select an option from magento backend for frontend development workflow to **"Client side less compilation".** After selecting it says less files are not accesiible 403 error. **Something like forbidden**. I had tried to run command for static deployment but it did not work. Also tried clearing out `pub/static` folders inside it, but couldn't work. Any ideas how to resolve?
[image]

Comment: I'm going through this right now. So strange it just seemed to start happening. I'll try to update this if I find a solution. Did you find anything?

Comment: @JustinP Well I didn't found any solution at that time, The only solution I have is to select the server side compilation again , and if there will be any change in less file, I just go to magento dashboard to clear and flush the cache. I know this is strange  but I didn't found the solution. If you find any solution please do post it. Thank you